# "Which is the ..." or "Which the ... is"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions, subjects, wh-questions

> I don't know which is the language.

Or

> I don't know which the language is.

Note that this is, of course, a positive sentence and not a question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say? That you don't know the language you're looking at or hearing—or that you don't know what language something should be in?

Comment: @JasonBassford Original sentence was "I don't know which is the original language" or "I don't know which the original language is".

Comment: Okay, so it's not your own sentence. It's ambiguous. There are different meanings. Without knowing the intended meaning, it's not possible to say which is *better* (if either is). What was the broader context? What came before and after that sentence?

Comment: It is indeed mine. Without using "which" I'd say "I don't know the original language", so since there was more than one option, I wanted to use "which".

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I misunderstood. Given the explanation, the current answer gives the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is very natural-sounding.

I suspect what you mean is:

> I don't know which language it is.

Without 'it' you are missing the object of the sentence that the verb 'is' relates to. Your mistake is in trying to make 'language' act as if it is the object, when in fact it is the thing the object of the sentence is being compared to.

Comment: I wanted to say something like: "I don't know the original language". So according to my suggestions it would be either "I don't know which is the original language" or "I don't know which the original language is". Is that correct?

Comment: @Enthusiastor Neither version sounds natural. I would use either the version in the answer, or *I don't know* ***what*** *that language is* or simply *I don't know* ***that*** *language*.